# Handling intent when receiving application is in the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

There 2 apps: First app can open the second one using:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my.path");
startActivity(intent);
```

this works fine.

Second app can call again the first app by using intents with actions. for example:

```
public void call(String number)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

And there lies a problem which I'll get to shortly.
I'm handling the received intent in the first app in the `onCreate` method. The first app is simply a single activity with many fragments which are switched with a fragment transaction. When receiving the intent from the second app, I'm making a transaction to a specific fragment according to the intent.

The problem is that when the first app is not in the background (meaning its close), my handling of the intent works fine. However, if the user opened the second app from the first one and the first one is still in the background, then when a user calls the intent in the second app, the first app is getting back to the foreground but to the same fragment the user was when he launched the second app, while I was expecting to show the new fragment which is based on the user's request in the intent sent from the second app.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this by overriding the OnNewIntent method handling the intent and bringing to top the required fragment.

Comment: Can't believe I did know about that method